# OBSOLETE - revisions/{id} is returning an error for locked posts

Tags: bug, status-completed, obsolete, revisions, locked-posts

The API is returning the following error message when I request the revision history for locked posts.

Example URL: http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/revisions/194812

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 500,
    "message": "A generic error has occurred on the server; developers have been notified."
  }
}
```

I've tried this through the [API Console](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/usage/methods/revisions), directly in my browser, and in code (with and without an API key).

Here's a sample from some of the top posts on Stack Overflow.

Locked:

- [List of freely available programming books](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/revisions/194812)
- [What is the single most influential book every programmer should read?](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/revisions/1711)
- [Hidden Features of C#?](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/revisions/9033)
- [Strangest language feature [closed]](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/revisions/1995113)
- [What are the lesser known but cool data structures?](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/revisions/500607)

Not locked:

- [Hidden features of Python](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/revisions/101268)
- [Flash CS4 refuses to let go](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/revisions/2193953)
- [What IDE to use for Python?](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/revisions/81584)
- [What is the name of this operator: “-->”?](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/revisions/1642028)
- [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/revisions/1732348)
- [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/revisions/388242)
- [Most useful free .NET libraries? [closed]](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/revisions/662956)

All of the **locked** questions give the error message above, while all of the questions that are not locked return a normal revision history.  Other question states like **closed** and **protected** seem to have no effect.

Finally, I did one last test.  I was able to successfully fetch the revision history of [Twitter image encoding challenge [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/891643/twitter-image-encoding-challenge) before it was locked (note that is was protected and closed prior to testing) but after it was locked I got [the same error message](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/revisions/891643).

Comment: @halfer It looks like it's fixed in the latest version. Deleted post ids return an empty list of items, but locked posts return a list of revisions. https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/revisions-by-ids#ids=9033&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true (I'll flag for a moderator to mark this completed.)